# Grouping like values and retrieving totals for a bar chart

Tags: 2010, list, chart-web-part

I have a list that is used for keeping records of taskings. The list contains a calculated column that creates a string to categorize the list items based off a few other fields and date. I would like to display a bar chart that can group the like items and display a count but I'm having difficulty displaying the data. To simplify I have data similar to this:

```
Title    CalculatedColumn
foo1      "2014 Q1"
foo2      "2014 Q1"
foo3      "2014 Q2"
bar1      "2014 Q1"
bar2      "2013 Q4"
```

Now I want to display a bar chart showing:

```
2013 Q4 - 1 item
2014 Q1 - 3 items
2014 Q2 - 1 item
```

How do I filter the data from the list to group and count like items? Do I need Visual Studio to perform that kind of calculation or can it be done with SharePoint Designer?

Comment: I haven't done SharePoint in a while but since this got a recent up vote I'll try to recall what I did to resolve this issue. I had to create a second list with the calculated column values, then add a count value to that table that was linked to my original table. Confusing I know. Basically my chart was then rendered based off of the new list. This may help http://pawansatope.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-count-related-lookup.html